# Using cookies to retain stylesheet preference across website

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cookies

I've got a simple javascript function which allows me to swap between different stylesheets in each page of my website. At the moment I don't have any cookies being implemented on the site so whenever I go to a new page the default stylesheet is loaded and if a user wanted to use the alternate stylesheet they would be forced to swap again. I want to make it to where by using cookies, whatever stylesheet the user chooses will remain when going to a different page.

Below I've got the following code which is my method of swapping stylesheets.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i=1;
    function styleSheet(){
        if(i%2==0){
            swapper('css/main.css');            
        }
        else{
            swapper('css/stylesheetalternate.css');             
        }
        i++;
    }
</script> 
<script>
    function swapper(select_sheet){
        document.getElementById('swapper').setAttribute('href', select_sheet);
    }
</script>
```

So far I haven't been able to get it to where the webpage would remember what the user chose as their stylesheet theme and when reloading the page keep the same stylesheet. This is my first time working with cookies and I'm mostly just looking for a way to implement this with my original javascript.

EDIT: Also just as a heads up, I only know front end web programming at this point. Based on Dave A's answer, would I adapt my current styleSheet() function as follows or is this not even necessary anymore? One thing I've had a bit of a hard time understanding is how the key works.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i=1;
    function styleSheet(){
        if(i%2==0){
            storeStyleSheet(sheet1, main.css);
        }
        else{
            storeStyleSheet(sheet2, alternate.css);             
        }
        i++;
    }
</script> 
<button onclick()="setStoredStyleSheet (styleSheetKey)">click here</button>
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616943/keep-website-theme-the-same-cookies

Comment: So based off that link, I would just use my current functions, but then what I'm unsure of is the set_theme function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I would use HTML 5 local storage to store the CSS filename:**

Store the user's selection with a function like:

```
    function storeStyleSheet(styleSheetKey, StyleSheetName){
       localStorage.setItem(styleSheetKey, StyleSheetName);
    }
```

And pull and use the stored CSS, if there is one:

```
    function setStoredStyleSheet(styleSheetKey){
    var styleSheet = localStorage.getItem(styleSheetKey);
        if(!(styleSheet=='undefined' || styleSheet==undefined) ){
            swapper(styleSheet);            
        }
        else{
            swapper('css/stylesheetalternate.css');             
        }
    }
```

I have found ***HTML 5 local storage*** to be easier to use than cookies. I have not had any problems using `localStorage` on any browser. And the interface is intuitive; just be aware that if the file/keyname was never stored before, it will return 'undefined' or undefined. There is also no automatic timeout with `localStorage`.

Comment: I've actually been kind of curious as to how using local storage works. So for the storeStyleSheet function would I just put all the different stylesheets that I currently have and give each one a unique key? Also, would I just create a button such as <button onclick="setStoredStyleSheet(key)>blah</button>" in order to allow users to alternate still?

Comment: @valrok I think you have exactly the right idea. Name ypur style sheets in meaningful ways like by the page name they apply to

Comment: @Valrok, the important thing is that each page have the name. You probably don't want to hard-code the CSS file you want to each page (by key or name). At this point architecture depends on your stack. If you are using a back-end, you should pass the keys, otherwise, you may want to hash by page/view name. I'm not sure if I'm answering your questions or not.

Comment: apologies for the late response. I should have specified earlier I'm only doing front-end as a hobby. One thing I'm slightly confused about is when storing a user's preference, if a user decides to swap stylesheets again will I have to do anything different or just use storestylesheet() again?

Comment: @valrok, if u want to store the new preference,  call identical.

Comment: Ok, and how do I know what the key is? When using storestylesheet() if I say storestylesheet(1, main.css) for example, does that apply 1 to be the key for main.css? That and will I need to use anything like window.onload to pull stored css or does that function do that by itself?

Comment: @Valrok, the function should probably be used to store the css file's name. Something like "PrimaryCSS", "main.css". But the function would not apply the css. If you want to see what gets stored, look at your stored cache in chrome `inspect element` -> `resources` -> `LocalStorage` or install the firebug LocalStorage extension. I assume `swapper()` can be used to apply the css.

Comment: Ok, one final question, with setstoredstylesheet() will I be putting the code in the head or body? I realize that setstoredstylesheet is pulling any stored stylesheets, but is this automatically running when a page is loaded or do I need to make it run somehow? I think I finally understand everything needed after this to get it all working exactly how I want it.

Comment: @Valrok, you should try to pull it on your `$(Ready)` event when the user first loads the page. Does that help?

Comment: Yes, I don't really have a $(ready) event for when a user loads a page, but that'll be the next thing I work on. I'm in no rush however, I enjoy this is a hobby and learning new things

Comment: @Valrok, use JQuery `$(){}`. Every statement you put inside is fired when page loads. Check this link http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easiest to pull in all the CSS (unless it's massive) and then apply a theme class to body/wherever you need it. And your CSS would look like

```
// common and default definitions

body.some-theme{
  // theme overrides of default go here
}

body.some-other-theme{
  // another theme
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a solution that remembers the user rather than the browser/ip address (remembering each browser has its own cookie jar) you'd probably best write this in a server side language with user preferences and only output the relevant CSS file using some server side processing.

However that's a much bigger question, to quickly solve the issue at hand consider the following.

Start by loading all CSS files, assuming they're not huge it probably won't make much difference speed wise, and it would mean the user could switch without the overhead of downloading extra data.

I agree with Dave A that the localStorage method is probably the best way to go about storing this info (without a server storing user preferences). So I suggest you write something similar to the following, I hacked this together rather quickly as I'm sure is rather apparent.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .default {
        background-color: blue;
      }

      .alternative {
        background-color: red;
      }
    </style>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      function init() {
        if (localStorage.getItem('cssName') !== "default") {
          var i = 0;
          var elems = [];
          var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('default');

          // Put the elements into an easy to interate array instead of HTML Collection.
          for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            elems.push(elements[i]);
          }

          // Iterate over the new nice array.
          elems.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
            element.setAttribute('class', 'alternative');    
          });
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body onload='init();'>
    <div class='default'>hbdfisubfiuodfhriubsrfiub</div>
    <div>iboufruewhiobieiohhbefpijbepojb</div>
    <div class='default'>hbdfisubfiuodfhriubsrfiub</div>
    <div>iboufruewhiobieiohhbefpijbepojb</div>
    <div class='default'>hbdfisubfiuodfhriubsrfiub</div>
    <div>iboufruewhiobieiohhbefpijbepojb</div>
    <div class='default'>hbdfisubfiuodfhriubsrfiub</div>
    <div>iboufruewhiobieiohhbefpijbepojb</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I forgot to mention this if you wish to go down the local storage route: http://mozilla.github.io/localForage/?javascript#localforage

Might be worth reading about.