# Read a cookie when implementing inside of another function

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have the following function to change stylesheets on my website that I want to use cookies to keep stylesheet theme persistent across pages.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i=1;
    function styleSheet(){
        if(i%2==0){
            swapper('css/main.css');    
            document.cookie = "username=Visitor";
        }
        else{
            swapper('css/stylesheetalternate.css'); 
            document.cookie = "username=alternateVisitor";
        }
        i++;
    }
<button onclick="styleSheet()">Click me</button>
```

I'm already setting my cookies inside of this function. I'm not too interested in setting expiration dates or anything like that, the default is fine for me. What I do want to try doing however is read the cookies inside of this function each time that I use the button I created. Is there no way to read it inside of the same function?

I'm aware that there exists a jquery library that does this, but I don't want to use jquery if I can get a better performance with javascript.

EDIT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i=1;
    function styleSheet(){
        if(i%2==0){
            swapper('css/main.css');    
            document.cookie = "username=Visitor";
            readCookie(Visitor);
        }
        else{
            swapper('css/stylesheetalternate.css'); 
            document.cookie = "username=alternateVisitor";
            readCookie(alternateVisitor);
        }
        i++;
    }
```

Do you mean something like the following when you say to use readCookie inside of my function? What I notice from this sort of implementation is that after swapping stylesheets once, it is for whatever reason impossible to swap again until the page is reloaded.

Comment: There are good reasons to stay away from jQuery, but performance isn’t really one of them; if it’s convenient, go for it. That said, [this library](https://github.com/js-coder/cookie.js) is good, and isn’t a jQuery plugin. [Consider also `localStorage`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage)

Comment: Agreed with @minitech, consider using using `storeStyleSheet` approach from your bounty question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699556/using-cookies-to-retain-stylesheet-preference-across-website/23736020#23736020

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a set of plain javascript cookie functions that you can use from any function.  So, to your question, you can call `readCookie("username")` from your function (or read any other cookie value):

```
// createCookie()
// name and value are strings
// days is the number of days until cookie expiration
// path is optional and should start with a leading "/" 
//   and can limit which pages on your site can 
//   read the cookie.
//   By default, all pages on the site can read
//   the cookie if path is not specified
function createCookie(name, value, days, path) {
    var date, expires = "";
    path = path || "/";
    if (days) {
        date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=" + path;
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name, "", -1);
}
```

Comment: So wait, what exactly do you mean by calling from my function readcookie("username")? What I don't understand is the use of 'name'. Are you saying that in my if conditions to simply call readCookie(name) with name in this case being either Visitor or alternateVisitor?

Comment: I edited my code to better show what I'm asking in terms of adding to my code.

Also, I don't see why I would need a function to create cookies when I'm not really trying to do anything that specific with them. Is there a reason why I shouldn't just create them the way I currently am?

Comment: @Valrok - when you read a cookie, you read its value and you do something with that value (that's the whole point of reading it in the first place).  The `readCookie()` function I gave you take one argument which is the cookie name (the left part of `name=value`) and it returns the value (the right part of `name=value`).  In your example, you would do something like `var name = readCookie("username")` and then do something with the `name` variable.  If you want further help, you will need to explain what cookie value you're trying to read and what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

document.cookies is just a big list of all the cookies. You can parse through it to find the one you're interested in:

```
function getCookieValue(cookieName) {
    var value = null;
    document.cookie.split(';')
        .forEach(function(pair){
            var pairArray = pair.split('=');
            if (pairArray[0]==cookieName) {
                value = pairArray[1];
            }
        });
    return value;
}
```

(Untested, let me know how it goes.)